# How do I model this relationship?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm building web app with a list of Reports where user can add some of them into favourite. Something like checkbox as a filter to display favourite only or all the reports. But don't know how to model this:

There are mine two entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastLogon { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string TileColour { get; set; }
    public string TileSize { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking about creating another entity FavouriteReports, but then how do I display all the reports?

Comment: What do you mean with 'display all the reports?'?

Comment: Let say I have 50 reports for all users, I would like to display a list of all those 50 reports, but also would like to use Favorite filter to display only the reports user added previously to his personal favourite.

Comment: Well, use a table to link reports to users as you suggested (FavouriteReports), and to get all reports just query the Report table?

Comment: That's what I through, but was hopping there is smarter solution

Comment: I think this is kind of the smartest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure a many-many relationship in your model, something like:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Report> FavouriteReports { get; set;}
}

public class Report
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<User> UserFavourites { get; set;}
}
```

This will need to create another many-many relationship table in your database.  You mention in the comments that you hoped there would be a smarter way - this is the smarter way (and proper DB design).

The many-many table will have two columns (userId and reportId), typically with a primary key covering both columns.

Comment: I don't understand where would I store favourites?